# Flask-Socket-IO, Nginx - has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: nginx, flask-socketio

I have a flask-socketio server deployed on ubuntu, and under /ect/nginx/sites-available/project
I have the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server-address;
    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            proxy_pass http://server-address;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
    }
    location /socket.io {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://server-address/socket.io;
    }
}
```

Even though I put in the `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;`, when I try to access the server from my client it still returns the error `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

The full request url is:

```
http://server-address/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1617319524463-0
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try adding the header on the /socket.io location as well? The error is for a Socket.IO route.

Comment: I did and then it said

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: You will need to create a small and complete example that shows this problem. If you do, I can give it a try and report back on this problem.

Comment: Hey, I worked it out. I needed cross origin only on flask, and I didn't need uswgi_pass parameter. also, because of the pass I was redirecting to the outside domain creating a recursive loop where I add the header each time. Thank you for the help